# Can't expose port for podman pod in macvlan network

Tags: ubuntu, networking, containers, podman

I'm using podman 3.4.4 on Ubuntu 22.04 and am trying to setup a pod with a macvlan network.  I'm running several other macvlan containers without issues, but when trying to setup a pod (caddy + a backend & a frontend in one pod) I can't expose port 80/443 as they are already exposed.

Setting up the pod:

```
podman pod create --name baz \
  --network foonet \
  --dns 192.0.2.2 \
  --ip 192.0.2.10 \
  -p 80:80 \
  -p 443:443
```

`foonet`:

```
podman network create -d macvlan\
  -o parent=bridgeexample \
  --subnet 192.0.2.0/24 \
  --gateway 192.0.2.1 \
  --ip-range 192.0.2.0/24 \
  foonet
```

One of the containers in the pod, exposes port 80/443:

```
podman create --pod baz \
  --name baz_caddy \
  caddy:latest
```

The typical error message I've seen:

```
Apr 11 21:19:37 atomic podman[4039059]: Error: error starting container 30e70a74280cf68b5c92eb7b0f6955ee9c2f53396fe2f7fd1c48964f28ed8738: cannot listen on the TCP port: listen tcp4 :80: bind: address already in use
```

If I try to expose the port on the IP I've assigned the container (`192.0.2.10:80:80`) I get:

```
bind: cannot assign requested address
```

Any ideas?

**Update:** larsks was right, trying to export ports when using macvlan is incorrect. I removed the ports and things started working.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to publish ports when using a macvlan network; the containers are attached directly to the network. If a service is listening on port 80, you can connect directly to port 80 on the appropriate ip. Drop the `-p 80:80` and `-p 443:443` and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you! I knew that but somehow forgot it while trying to setup this. I then ran into another issue (containers expected a certain naming convention which I had deviated from) which was easily solved by --add-host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks) solved the issue, I had an accident while thinking I should expose ports for macvlan backed networks.